# How to find if any of elements within an array are within range between 50 and 99 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, any

This is given array:

```
var a = [2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 42, 55, 67, 89, 95, 102, 108, 112];
```

How to find if ANY of the elements from the array a are within range of 50 to 99? To return true if ANY of these elements are within range 50 to 99, and false if not!

How to find if ALL of the elements of this array a are within range of 50 to 99? To return true if ALL of these elements are within range 50 to 99 and false if at least one element is outside this range!

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Comment: [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)   [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: @Ivan Vrzogic, did you have a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Array#some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array#every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
var a = [2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 42, 55, 67, 89, 95, 102, 108, 112];

console.log("some", a.some(value => value > 50 && value < 99));
console.log("every", a.every(value => value > 50 && value < 99));
```

also check out the other array methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays functions *some* and *every* for this.
In this solution I assumed that 50 and 99 are inclusive and they are also valid values.

> How to find if ANY of the elements from the array a are within range
> of 50 to 99? To return true if ANY of these elements are within range
> 50 to 99, and false if not!

You can use *.some()*

```
a.some((x) => x >= 50 && x <= 99)
```

> How to find if ALL of the elements of this array a are within range of
> 50 to 99? To return true if ALL of these elements are within range 50
> to 99 and false if at least one element is outside this range!

You can use *.every()*

```
a.every((x) => x >= 50 && x <= 99)
```

```js
var a = [2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 42, 55, 67, 89, 95, 102, 108, 112];


console.log(a.some((x) => x >= 50 && x <= 99));
console.log(a.every((x) => x >= 50 && x <= 99));
```

Here you can read more

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 42, 55, 67, 89, 95, 102, 108, 112];

//if at least one element in the range of 50 and 99
console.log(a.filter(e => e >= 50 && e <= 99).length > 0)

//if all elements are in the range of 50 and 99
console.log(a.filter(e => e >= 50 && e <= 99).length === a.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const A = [2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 42, 55, 67, 89, 95, 102, 108, 112];

console.log('#1 ', A.some(element => element > 50 && element < 99))

console.log('#2 ', A.every(element => element > 50 && element < 99))
```